# spartacus 4.2.1 B2B site in CX 2105.3 not able to add to cart

Tags: angularjs, spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new to Spartacus. When I try to add a product to the cart. I'm getting the following message. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5unMA.png)
The error occurs in the anonymous user and Logged in User.

I have tried what in the Spartacus documentation has ben written. But I haven't been able to fix it. I also tried to give all authentication to a user in the backoffice. But didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the error message from OCC call for adding to cart (you can check it e.g. by opening of Chrome DevTools -> Network tab).

From top of my head: Currently, for B2B storefront, you need to use the B2B variations of the OCC endpoints - see [defaultB2bOccConfig](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/c1b4146e7230891cc340cfaf07aec382937a27ff/core-libs/setup/recipes/b2b/config/default-b2b-occ-config.ts). Perhaps you're missing the B2B-flavoured configuration of OCC endpoints in your Spartacus app. Please try providing in your app module (or in your `SpartacusConfigurationModule`):

```
import { defaultB2bOccConfig } from "@spartacus/setup";

/* ... */


providers: [
  /* ... */,
  provideConfig(defaultB2bOccConfig)
]
```

Comment: I work together with OP, this was the issue, we weren't using the B2B variation. Thanks a lot!